# powershell to change existing email from text format to html body format

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have working code which adds html to html-format emails received in Outlook. This works fine, now want to extend this to "text only" emails.

My plan was to copy the content of (text)body to htmlbody to convert the mail to html format, but somehow the resulting email is always empty. The `Write-Output` looks ok though.

```
$textcontent = $item.Body.ToString() 
Write-Output $textcontent
$item.HTMLBody = $textcontent | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style
$item.Save()
```

So it seems the underlying problem is that `$item.Body` is of type `system.object` and not a `string` and seems not to be converted properly?

Any ideas I could try?

Comment: what happens if you set `$item.IsBodyHtml = $true` before the save (or even before you put in the HTMLBody ??

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Theo, unfortunately I get the following error message:       
 `Exception setting "IsBodyHtml": "The property 'IsBodyHtml' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."At
1:57 char:4
+             $item.IsBodyHtml = $true
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting`

Comment: Ok, so what type of object is `$item` exactly and what properties/methods does it have?

Comment: I tried `$item.BodyFormat = 2` but also no effect

Comment: Ok, so it is not a MailMessage type object apparently, but then.. What IS it?
You need to do a `$item | Get-Member` or `$item | Select-Object -Property *` to figure out what you can actuallu do with it..

Comment: Both `$item | Get-Member` and `$item | Select-Object -Property *` dont produce any output. Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the [BodyFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-bodyformat-property-outlook) property of the MailItem class. There is no need to convert the existing body text and set the `HTMLBody` property.

If you do any modifications to the HTML markup of bodies make sure you get a well-formed HTML markup as a result.

Comment: Thank you Eugene, this is working for me. Sometimes you need to think simple :)